# how to display the CPU percentage usage by each process in cmd

Tags: command-line, cmd

i want to a cmd windows command to display the all the processes and the cpu percentage for each process.
is there a command which give me this result?
can you help me please?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a tasklist's CPU time to CPU % usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206805/how-to-convert-a-tasklists-cpu-time-to-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [pslist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896682.aspx) from the SysInternals-powered pstools.

You will need to download them from that link and put the tools in your cmd directory (or chdir to wherever they are).

Use `-s` to see the CPU usage of each process.

Comment: Hi, you can run "pslist -s 1" it will run for a second and exit, without updating.

Comment: this number is the percentage cpu or the cpu time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35912/discussion-between-alexdev-and-ofloflofl)

Comment: Very nice! However my server is virtually seized, I have like 100 CPU cycles to work with, literally! `tasklist` takes ages to run. So downloading and installing is not an option ATM. I will remember to do so after I resolve this CPU hog problem, if I ever do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`Perfmon` can use a wildcard to get the CPU usage for each running process.  It also has the text interface `typeperf` which spits the results out to the console.

This command will produce a one-line CSV output of the current running process CPU usage:

`typeperf "\process(*)\% processor time" -sc 1`

The PID is missing from this report.  If you need, you can add the PID for each of the processes as a separate counter to log, then match up the names:

`typeperf "\process(*)\% processor time" "\process(*)\id process" -sc 1`