# reduce the line of pslist -s command and display the CPU percentage for each process

Tags: cmd, cpu, cpu-usage

i use this command in cmd to know the cpu used by each process:

```
C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\PSTools\\pslist.exe -s
```

this command return more than 5000 line, why?
and how can i reduce this number of line?
and is there  a way to display the ""percentage"" CPU usage for each process instead of CPU time?and how can display only the CPU column instead of all columns
thanks...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/53075560/1290634

Answer (score 0):

This uses a helper batch file called repl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
pslist -s -r 2|repl "^(\w+)[ ]*(\w+)[ ]*(\w+)[ ]*.*" "$3 - $1"
```

Tested with:
pslist v1.3 - Sysinternals PsList

It runs continuously so the output never stops.