# How to use cmd command "tasklist" to list all processes and it;s cpu usage?

Tags: cmd, tasklist

I want to list all processes and it's cpu usage,
Can the "tasklist" command acheive?[image]

I want to list Image Name,PID,and CPUUsage througn cmd command
like this,
but it has no cpu usage

[image]

Comment: What do you want, exactly? Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a tasklist's CPU time to CPU % usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206805/how-to-convert-a-tasklists-cpu-time-to-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 2):

use `tasklist /v`.

You may want to set `mode 240` before, or redirect output to a file:

```
tasklist /v >tasklist.txt
```

(sorry, `tasklist` does not support selection of which properties to show; only "standard" view or "verbose" view)

Comment: How to convert cpu time to cpu usage?I want to get the cpu usage,it's better be percentage

Comment: CPU usage is a momentary value. You might catch it in the very millisecond where it peaks to 99% or another millisecond, where it's idle (0%). It doesn't tell you anything about CPU load, because you don't know if it's 99% at 90% of the overall time or 0,001%.

Comment: I just want to know the cpu usage at the moment I run,just like the first picture I posted

Comment: @elsonwx related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206805/how-to-convert-a-tasklists-cpu-time-to-cpu-usage

Comment: Then there's this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720901/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process-with-tasklist-in-windows